# How to implement a search bar on Flask web application?

Tags: sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-3.8, whoosh

I am trying to implement a search bar on my Flask web application. As I am a beginner in web programming, I have to search around for ways to do it and I saw the option to use flask_whooshalchemy. However, I have also seen people commenting about how this extension is no longer supported and it is incompatible with Python 3 (I am currently using the python 3.8.2).

I have tried installing through 'pip3 install flask-whooshalchemy' and it is said to be installed. But when I entered 'import flask_whooshalchemy' in the REPL, it gives ModuleNotFound error. I have tried to install flask_whooshalchemyplus through pip but it returns error with exit status 1.

May I ask if there is any other ways for me to implement the search bar or if I can download flask-whooshalchemy in an alternative way? Thank you in advance!

Comment: mybe this helps you https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvi-full-text-search (elasticsearch)

Comment: @sq125 - What database are you using?

Comment: @cizario thanks, ill check it out!

Comment: @pjcunningham Im using sqlite